# how to configure claim base authentication in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, fba

For our sharepoint 2010 app's we need form base authentication(Claim base authentication).
Is anybody help me on same issue?

Thanks,
Nandy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blogs.technet.com/wbaer/archive/2010/04/14/claims-based-identity-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx